# Wrapper upgrading in JavaScript (YUI )

Tags: javascript, wrapper, yui

Firstly, I am doing a case study in upgrading in YUI library from YUI 2.9 to YUI 3.18.
Here is a wrapper which is using YUI2 declaration in this way

```
var MyButton = function (parentWindow, buttonElem) {
    this.parentWindow = parentWindow;
    this.id = buttonElem.id;

    MyButton.superclass.constructor.call(this, buttonElem, {
        visibility : buttonElem.style.visibility,
        className : buttonElem.className
    });
    this.element = $(this.id);
    this.button = $(this.element.querySelector("button"));
    this.button.accessKey = buttonElem.accessKey;
    parentWindow.addChildElement(this.id, this);
};

YAHOO.extend(MyButton, YAHOO.widget.Button, {
    init : function (el, userConfig) {
        el.style.visibility = userConfig.visibility;
        this.addClass(userConfig.className);
        MyButton.superclass.init.call(this, el, userConfig);
        this.subscribe("click", this.onClick, this, true);
        this.subscribe("dblclick", this.ondblClick, this, true);
        this.subscribe("focus", this.onFocus, this, true);
        this.subscribe("blur", this.onBlur, this, true);
        this.subscribe("mouseup", this.onmouseUp, this, true);
        this.subscribe("mousedown", this.onmouseDown, this, true);
    }
});
```

And here is the modified code after trying to upgrade to YUI3.18

```
var MyButton = function (parentWindow, buttonElem) {
    this.parentWindow = parentWindow;
    this.id = buttonElem.id;

    MyButton.superclass.constructor.call(this, buttonElem, {
        visibility : buttonElem.style.visibility,
        className : buttonElem.className
    });
    this.element = $(this.id);
    this.button = $(this.element.querySelector("button"));
    this.button.accessKey = buttonElem.accessKey;
    parentWindow.addChildElement(this.id, this);
};
YUI().use('button','oop',function(Y){
Y.extend(MyButton , Y.Button, {
        init : function (el, userConfig) {
        el.style.visibility = userConfig.visibility;
        this.addClass(userConfig.className);
        MyButton.superclass.init.call(this, el, userConfig);
        this.subscribe("click", this.onClick, this, true);
        this.subscribe("dblclick", this.ondblClick, this, true);
        this.subscribe("focus", this.onFocus, this, true);
        this.subscribe("blur", this.onBlur, this, true);
        this.subscribe("mouseup", this.onmouseUp, this, true);
        this.subscribe("mousedown", this.onmouseDown, this, true);
    }
});
```

This is showing me error " Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined " at the line

```
 MyButton.superclass.constructor.call(this, buttonElem, {
```

Where am I going wrong? What can I change to get as expected?

Note: This is just a part of the code where I have changed the code and the one using YUI2.9 is working perfectly alright.

Comment: `some kind of error` - you'll need *some kind of* solution then

Comment: Sorry,"Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" this is the Error

Comment: `toLowerCase` isn't on that line or anywhere in the code you posted, so that's pretty damned hard for us to debug for you

Comment: Sorry, I was not permitted to provide much more info than this, But can u say me is this what I have done in upgrading is right or wrong.

Comment: Is it right or wrong? Does it work?

Comment: The first piece of code i.e. using YUI 2.9 which is perfectly alright and the second piece of code i.e. using YUI3.18 which was written by me and reporting me "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" for changing here and it's not working.

Comment: I understand what the error is, you seem to be asking if you "did it right" ... clearly you did not, as you are getting an error ... but there's no **clue** as to which part of your code is causing the error

Comment: Sorry, and I will be back after knowing more and I will be editing and will try to provide more information if possible.Thanking You.